# How do I make WcfTestClient generate metadata with enableDataBinding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcftestclient

When launching a wcf service which has DataContracts that have properties that inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged I get an error from the WCFTestClient while loading the service reference
 CS0644: 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler' cannot derive from special class 'System.MulticastDelegate'

I have since determined that if I want the service reference to work I need to pass the extra option to svcutil /edb

Will WcfTestClient use svcutil and how can I default that when the wcftestclient uses svcutil that it adds the additional option /edb